# How can I group elements in a navbar so they stack as one unit for responsive scaling

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-5

I have a navbar with four elements: a logo, Org Name, home button, and a dropdown button

I want to group them into two sets [ logo + Org name ] and [ home + dropdown ]
so that they stack vertically as two rows when the screen size gets too small. Currently the buttons stack vertically before they move under the logo and org name.

```
[ logo + Org name ]
[ home ]
[ dropdown ]
```

Code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-body-tertiary">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div class="d-flex order-0 order-sm-0 align-items-center">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="navbar-brand"   <!--##logo##-->
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbarMiddle">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active"   <!--##Org Name##-->
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex order-1 order-sm-1 align-items-center">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link"   <!--##Home Button##-->
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"   <!--##Dropdown Button##-->
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end dropdown-menu-dark">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item"
```

I have tried to wrap the ul in spans and div tags with different attributes, which hasn't worked.
Using a table works, but breaks the functionality of the dropdown.
i understand that this is caused by flexbox behavior, where the Bootstrap scss changes the         `flex-direction: row  @media (min-width: 576px)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did manage to solve my problem by putting each item into their own <ul class="navbar-nav">